# Implementing Put Block of Azure rest api?

Tags: rest, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am following this MSDN Reference (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/put-block) to implement a rest call for Put Block.

I am coding in Java and I formed below Authorisation string and URL before signing.

```
PUT


364070








x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-date:Fri, 20 Jan 2017 12:57:06 GMT
x-ms-version:2016-05-31
/xyz/mycontainer/imageBlock1
comp:block
sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/imageBlock1?comp=block&blockid=YmxvY2stMQ==

Error I am getting:
403
    Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
```

I read gaurav mantras post http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/. But, its not working for me.

> Is there anything wrong with the string I am sending to sign or URL or
>   below httpConn Request Header.

The Http Header I am setting is:

```
httpConn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
                httpConn.setRequestProperty("x-ms-blob-type", blobType);
                httpConn.setRequestProperty("x-ms-date", date);
                httpConn.setRequestProperty("x-ms-version", storageServiceVersion);
                httpConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
                httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",String.valueOf(blobLength) );

                System.out.println(httpConn);

                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpConn.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(bytes);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
                int response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: What is 'authorizationHeader'. Have you prefix it with "Bearer: "?

Comment: You have comp:block in your string to sign but not blockid:YmxvY2stMQ==. Also, please ensure that there is no newline at the end of the last query parameter in the string to sign. Finally, always check the response body when you get 403. In case of signature mismatch, the service will return the string to sign that it used and you can compare to your own.

Comment: Have you solved this issue, any updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I known, [Put Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/put-block) is a operation against Block Blobs. So, we do not need to specify `x-ms-blob-type` header. If you specify this in your HTTP header, you need to follow the following [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services) about constructing the Canonicalized Headers String:

- Retrieve all headers for the resource that begin with **x-ms-**, including the x-ms-date header.
- Convert each HTTP header name to **lowercase**.
- **Sort** the headers lexicographically by header name, in ascending order. Each header may appear only once in the string.
- Finally, **append a new-line character to each canonicalized header** in the resulting list. Construct the CanonicalizedHeaders string by concatenating all headers in this list into a single string.

So, based on your code, your `canonicalized headers` string looks like:

`x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:Fri, 20 Jan 2017 12:57:06 GMT\nx-ms-version:2016-05-31\n`

Moreover, the `CanonicalizedResource` you built is incorrect. Based on your code, it should look as follows:

`/{account-name}/{container-name}/{blob-name}\nblockid:{block-id}\ncomp:block`

**Note:** For more details about constructing the `Canonicalized Resource` String, you could refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services).

The `StringToSign` would look like this:

[image]

And the traffic captured by Fiddler as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was confused because in the format of canonical resource there was no mention to include blockid.